# Sharing component MicroFrontend between an Angular and AngularJS application

Tags: angular, angularjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am creating custom web components using Angular (14). It works fine in the Angular application. But when I am planning to use it in AngularJS, I need some help.

How can I use custom web components from microfronted into another? Are there any articles or sample example links which can guide me further?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Your question is kind of broad. Usually, web components are registered globally on your site. So if one microfrontend registers a webcomponent you can use it in every microfrontend

Comment: @Lalaluka  : To start over, i created a  Microfrontend app using single-spa and have one app in angular and another in angularjs.  I created web component using angular elements and  able to use web component in angular application. But unable to see the web component when the single-spa uses angularjs code for displaying the application. So i was trying to figure out if there is a way for inter-communication among different micro-frontend app.
I created a web component in angular

Comment: What is *"microfronted"*?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be looking in to **Webpack Module Federation**.
It helps one JavaScript application to use another easily.
This concept is used commonly in angular micro front-ends.

Please read https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/

And go through this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908854/14673615

Hope this helps

Comment: This question is about web components in single-spa not microfrontends with module federation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).